# JAGS Cannot insert node into P[1:3,1:100]. Dimension mismatch

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags

I am new to JAGS and trying to replicate results from a textbook I have been reading. When I run my code I am persistently getting the error

> Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  :
> RUNTIME ERROR:
> Cannot insert node into P[1:3,1:100]. Dimension mismatch

The data file "haplotype.csv" is available at [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/DATA/haplotype.html](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/CASI_files/DATA/haplotype.html).

Here is my code:

````
"A practice analysis replicating the results of 'Computer Age Statistical Inference' section 13.5"

library(tidyverse)
library(R2jags)

haplotype <- read_csv('haplotype.csv') %>% 
  rename(id = X1)

# preprocessing as per p. 258
expand_genotype <- function(data_in){
  loci <- data_in %>% 
    select(-id, -race)
  loci_expanded <- data_in %>% 
    select(id, race) %>% 
    mutate(origin_1 = case_when(race == 'Japanese' ~ 1,
                                race == 'European' ~ 2,
                                TRUE ~ 3),
           origin_2 = origin_1) %>% 
    select(-race)
  for (m in 1:ncol(loci)){
    gene <- colnames(loci)[m]
    G_m <- loci[,m] %>% 
      as_vector()
    X_1_m <- c()
    X_2_m <- c()
    for (i in 1:length(G_m)){
      G_im <- G_m[i]
      if (G_im == 0){
        X_1_im <- 0
        X_2_im <- 0
      } else if (G_im == 1){
        X_1_im <- 1
        X_2_im <- 0
      } else {
        X_1_im <- 1
        X_2_im <- 1
      }
      X_1_m <- c(X_1_m, X_1_im)
      X_2_m <- c(X_2_m, X_2_im)
    }
    colname1 <- paste0(gene, '_c1')
    colname2 <- paste0(gene, '_c2')
    G_m_expanded <- tibble(col1 = X_1_m, col2 = X_2_m)
    colnames(G_m_expanded) <- c(colname1, colname2)
    if (any(X_1_m + X_2_m != G_m)){
      print(m)
      stop('Improper genotype expansion occured.')
    }
    loci_expanded <- loci_expanded %>% 
      bind_cols(G_m_expanded)
  }
  return(loci_expanded)
}

haplotype2 <- haplotype %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  expand_genotype()


# Set up the Gibbs sampler

model <- "
  model {
    for (i in 1:168){  
      Z[i, 1] ~ dmulti(Q[i], 1)
      Z[i, 2] ~ dmulti(Q[i], 1)
      j <- Z[i, 1]
      for (m in 1:100){
        X[i, m*2-1] ~ dbin(P[j, m], 1)
        X[i, m*2] ~ dbin(P[j, m], 1)
      }
    }
    Q[1:168] ~ ddirch(c(1, 1, 1))
    P[1:3, 1:100] ~ ddirch(c(1, 1))
  }
"

writeLines(model,'model.txt')

Z <- haplotype2 %>% 
  select(origin_1, origin_2) %>% 
  as.matrix()
X <- haplotype2 %>% 
  select(-id, -origin_1, -origin_2) %>% 
  as.matrix()

jags_data <- c('Z', 'X')
params <- c('Q', 'P')

sim <- jags(data=jags_data,inits=NULL,
            parameters.to.save=params,
            model.file='model.txt',
            n.iter=2000, n.burnin=1000,
            n.chains=1,n.thin=0)
sim
```
````